# How to convert jquery ui.selectable.js plugin into a function?

Tags: jquery, css, listbox

Background - 
I have a list of elements with alternating row CSS styles. I need to make this list selectable using `ctrl` and `shift` key. individual mouse click selects one element, `ctrl` key lets you select multiple elements and shift key helps selecting group of elements.

For this task I need to achieve functionality like `jquery.ui.selectable.js` plugin but without using the actual plugin.

Problem - 
I don't understand how to skip `_mouseStart`, `_mouseStop` functions from plugin. I need to get the plugin like functionality from a user created function. Could anyone please guide me on this?
Thanks.

Comment: please provide a fiddle with what you have done so far

Comment: I am deciding between approaches
1) to use $.fn.myfunction() 
2) to write click handlers ( click event ) on list items and for selection check shift and ctrl keys.
I would like to know which would be a better approach to achieve this functionality.